# Mobile Intel 4 Series Express Chipset Family performance improvement

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I just purchased a laptop with the Mobile Intel 4 Series Express chipset with 1308 MB of memory. I know its no Nvidia or ATi card but 1308 MB still looks like a lot to me.

Is there any way I could improve graphics performance especially while playing games?

Answer (score 1):

Well, its still an integrated chip, and you're going to get that kind of performance. its not just about graphics ram, its also various internal factors such as shader units, and what it supports - they're a lot better than anything intel's put out but only are at par with low end discrete graphics.

there's some murmuring the desktop varient is [overclockable](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4083/the-sandy-bridge-review-intel-core-i7-2600k-i5-2500k-core-i3-2100-tested/4), but no word about the laptop chipsets.

Your best bet is to tweak the game settings, and hope it works